# Reconnecting secondary DRBD node

Tags: linux, debian, software-raid, drbd

I have set up test DRBD installation succesfully, with switching, synchronization etc working correctly.

But I also wanted to test the reliatbility of the setup, so I gave it a good "trashing" like disconnecting network interfaces midflight, etc. In the course of such testing I have "managed" to get secondary to `Diskless` state:

```
root@h2 ~ % drbd-overview 
 0:r0/0  Connected Secondary/Primary Diskless/UpToDate
```

Now I cannot connect the resource back:

```
root@h2 ~ % drbdadm  --discard-my-data connect r0
r0: Failure: (102) Local address(port) already in use.
Command 'drbdsetup-84 connect r0 ipv4:10.0.1.90:7788 ipv4:10.0.0.90:7788 --protocol=C --max-buffers=36k --sndbuf-size=1024k --rcvbuf-size=2048k --discard-my-data' terminated with exit code 10
```

*Even rebooting secondary does not help* (I still get the message `r0: Failure: (102) Local address(port) already in use.`

Primary:

```
root@h1 ~ % drbd-overview 
 0:r0/0  Connected Primary/Secondary UpToDate/Diskless
```

Configuration:

```
root@h1 ~ % cat /etc/drbd.d/r0.res 
resource r0 {
        protocol C;
        startup {
                wfc-timeout  15;
                degr-wfc-timeout 60;
        }
        disk {
                on-io-error     detach;
                c-fill-target   10M;
                c-max-rate      700M;
                c-plan-ahead    7;
                c-min-rate      4M;
        }
        net {
                # max-epoch-size  20000;
                max-buffers       36k;
                sndbuf-size       1024k;
                rcvbuf-size       2048k;
        }
        syncer {
                rate                    400M;
                al-extents              6433;
        }
        on h1 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/sdc1;
                address 10.0.0.90:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        on h2 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/vg/drbdtest2;
                address 10.0.1.90:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
}
```

OS:

```
% lsb_release -a
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:    9.6
Codename:   stretch

% dpkg -l | grep drbd
ii  drbd-utils                                    8.9.10-2                                   amd64        RAID 1 over TCP/IP for Linux (user utilities)
```

Answer (score 0):

DRBD is already `Connected`, but it's in a `Diskless` disk state. This means that there is either something wrong with the backing disk causing it to throw IO errors, or something else is preventing DRBD from accessing that disk.

`/var/log/syslog` should be full of messages surrounding the issue, but you can also try a, `drbdadm attach r0` from the node that's `Diskless` to see what it tells you.